# Can't get rid of shadow under Android Button

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable

I have a Android Button that I'm placing on my screen, and am defining a custom background drawable that just specifies a green rectangle for now. But, for some reason there appears to be a very thin shadow being drawn under my button (highlighted with the red box):[image]

Is there any way to get rid of this while still using a Button? It because really ugly when I change my background drawable to have rounded corners.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's see the **really ugly**. By the way, are you using `Lollipop` and/or a `Material theme`?

Comment: Set style to `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle` and tweak from there?

Comment: On Material you need to set android:stateListAnimator="@null" to remove the default elevation animator. Alternatively, just use View if you don't want the default Button styling.

Answer (score 9):

@alanv's comment was the correct answer: "On Material you need to set android:stateListAnimator="@null" to remove the default elevation animator. Alternatively, just use View if you don't want the default Button styling"

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

`style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.