# How to remove button shadow (android)

Tags: android, button, shadow

I want to remove the shadow from the button to make it seem more flat.

I have this right now:

[image: cancel button with shadow]

But I want this:

[image: cancel button without shadow]

Comment: I write comment here, it's work for me.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867284/remove-shadow-effect-on-android-button/30856094#30856094][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867284/remove-shadow-effect-on-android-button/30856094#30856094

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408240/cant-get-rid-of-shadow-under-android-button

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Another alternative is to add

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

to your Button xml as documented here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

An example would be

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

Comment: This removes the button style, e.i. the shadow and emboss. Adding a selector with shapes is optional. This is a more accurate answer.

Comment: In addition, I use a custom style for my button. you can extend your custom style from : 

    <style name="MyCustomButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">

Answer (score 238):

A simpler way to do is adding this tag to your button:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

though it requires API level 21 or more..

Comment: @Alon Kogan, is there any backward compatibility for using the `android:stateListAnimator ` attribute?

Comment: This solution allows you to create a style bot having to inherit from `borderlessButtonStyle` style, which gives you more flexibility.

Comment: this is only solution which is worked for me, borderlessButtonStyle tag didn't work, since I need to get rid off the shadow while button is being pressed

Comment: Works on MaterialButton too

Comment: This is a better solution for me, it keeps the ripple effect

Comment: Why I can't set this as `item` in button `style`?

Comment: Thanks for the solution! mind elaborate why tag works?

Answer (score 119):

**Kotlin**

```
stateListAnimator = null
```

---

**Java**

```
setStateListAnimator(null);
```

---

**XML**

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Comment: Requires API level 21 or higher

Comment: after settings stateListAnimator to null button becomes invisible, anyone experiencing this?

Comment: This removes more than just the shadow.

Answer (score 63):

I use a custom style

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"></style>
```

Don't forget to add

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

otherwise the button text will be in UpperCase.

Answer (score 36):

Material desing buttons add to button xml:
 `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"`

Comment: Sometimes it is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004981/2914140, but a gray button in disabled state becomes lighter.

Answer (score 28):

try : `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`

Comment: Although this may solve the OP’s problem, I’d recommend to add some context to it. Why will it help? Also, “try this” is a bit misleading. Are you sure it will solve the problem, or just guessing? If so, you should write a comment instead.

Comment: It requires API 21.

Answer (score 18):

It requires API level 21

```
        android:outlineProvider="none"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using this as the background for your button might help, change the color to your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_light" />
            <padding
                android:left="8dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_dark" />
            <padding
                android:left="8dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? It didn't remove the drop shadow for me.

Comment: it replaces original background with shadows, with this background with solid color

Answer (score 4):

All above answers are great, but  I will suggest an other option:

```
<style name="FlatButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
 <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
 <!-- more style custom here --> 
</style>
```

Comment: It is similar to Alon Kogan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122825/2914140).

Comment: how is this different than 5ish of above?

Answer (score 3):

the @Alt-Cat answer work for me!

R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle doesn't contain shadow.

and the document of button is great.

Also, you can set this style on your custom button, in second constructor.

```
    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a Button, you can use a TextView and add a click listener in the java code.

I.e.

in the activity layout xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="@string/btn_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

in the activity java file:

```
TextView btnTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_text_view);
btnTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // handler code
            }
        });
```

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, but you actually helped me to fix my issue with a similar problem, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
 android:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

For me `android:outlineProvider="none"` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

### Update for Material Components

If you've previously used something like this:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>
</style>

<style name="NoShadowButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
</style>
```

And like me you're scratching your head wondering why it doesn't work anymore now that you've migrated to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.*`, it's because buttonStyle refers only to the AppCompat button style - there is a new style for materialButtonStyle. This fixed the issue for me:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton</item>
</style>
```

Here's a [good guide](https://material.io/blog/migrate-android-material-components) on what else has changed, and how to migrate properly.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom button; use the style `R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless`, Kotlin way-

```
class CSButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned here before, but if you want to have a Material Button without shadow you can achieve it by creating following custom style:

```
<style name="materialButtonNoShadow" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
```

And then just apply it in your xml layout:

```
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/noShadowButton"
            style="?attr/materialButtonNoShadow"/>
```