# Android Button with rounded corners, ripple effect and no shadow

Tags: android, button, rounded-corners, ripple

I am trying to build Android Button with rounded corners. But along the rounded corners (bottom left & right corner), there is unwanted grey color shadow around it.

[image: rounded corner button]

Here's my code:

`drawable/my_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffa6c575" />
        <solid android:color="#ffa6c575"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
      </shape>
    </item>
  </selector>
```

Then in layout xml file, I have:

```
<LinearLayout
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="BUY" />

  <View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
  </View>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/sell_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="SELL" />

</LinearLayout>
```

1) How can I get rid of the extra grey color shadow around rounded corners (bottom left & right corner)?

2) Button has default ripple effect. How can I maintain the default ripple effect?

Comment: Button has default shadow. You can change to TextView which is a base class of Button and has less default values.

Comment: For redundant border issue, I solves it with `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" `. Anyone has any idea how to get back the default ripple effect?

Comment: @Shuwn Yuan Tee You need to use custom ripple drawable.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I finally solved it with below code. This achieve rounded corners for button. Also, for Android Version >= V21, it uses ripple effect. For earlier Android version, button color changes when it is clicked, based on `android:state_pressed, android:state_focused`, etc.

In `layout xml` file:

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/green_trading_button_effect"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="BUY" />
```

For button onclick ripple effect (Android >= v21) :

`drawable-v21/green_trading_button_effect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_material_dark">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_trading_button" />
</ripple>
```

For earlier Android version, just change background color during onclick:

`drawable/green_trading_button_effect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_trading_button_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_trading_button_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_trading_button_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_trading_button" />
</selector>
```

`drawable/green_trading_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffa6c575"/>
    <!-- rounded corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

`drawable/green_trading_button_selected.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffc5dca8"/>
    <!-- corners corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: If you also want a 'disabled' in the ripple, add an `item` to the root of `ripple` and a `selector` to that item. Then, just use normally: an `item` for the content of the ripple in this answer here and one that is `item state_enabled=false` with the desired design. Something like: [https://pastebin.com/TQuYYbg0](https://pastebin.com/TQuYYbg0)

Comment: `android:color="@color/ripple_material_dark"` is a private resource, as a result, no ripple effect was being displayed. I added another colour in my `@color` folder and replaced `android:color="@color/ripple_material_dark"` with `android:color="@color/my_gray_color"` and ripple effect displayed smoothly.

Answer (score 24):

> drawable/ripple_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp" android:bottomRightRadius="25dp" android:topLeftRadius="25dp" android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

> drawablev21/ripple_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_white">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
                android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

> drawable/button_circle_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

> drawable/circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/ripple_white" />
</shape>
```

> Setting style and ripple to Button

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/choose_folder"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_circle_background"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_circle"
            android:text="Chose Folder"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

inspired by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530064/9008878)

this will add perfect round corners ripple effect to button with round cornered shape and also no shadow

[gif of button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15bZ9.gif)

Answer (score 12):

Try setting this in your xml. This worked for me.

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Also, if you are targeting API level 21 and above you can use

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

This link has more answers [How to remove button shadow (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756035/how-to-remove-button-shadow-android/30758869#30758869)

Comment: `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" ` works too, thanks!

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 7):

**drawable file for design shape of the button intent of using  use  that's it.**

> drawable/ripper_button_effect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
  <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
      <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_button_shape"></item>
</ripple>
```

**use in XML**

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ripper_button_effect"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your drawable file make a file like this:

button_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/blue_500" />
</shape>
```

Increase radius to make it more curved.

And in your XML for button, give style borderless to button and background that you made it like in the top:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/task_action_btn"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:clipToPadding="false"` to your `<Button></Button>` views

Answer (score 0):

Try this in code

```
Button buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy_button);
Button sellButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sell_button);

hideShadow(buyButton);
hideShadow(sellButton);


public void hideShadow(Button button) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        button.setElevation(0);
    }
}
```